# PHP localhost no longer sending emails due to TLS1.2 requirement

Tags: php, email, tls1.2, sendmail

PHP (v 8.0.13) mail (via sendmail) sends me an email from an overnight script which runs on my Windows 11 PC (localhost). The mail is delivered via an SMTP connection to my mail account on IONOS. All worked fine until IONOS switched to requiring TLS 1.2 security. Regular emailing from Outlook with the account works OK.

Reading that (my) sendmail probably didn't support TLS 1.2 I upgraded to a newer version (https://github.com/sendmail-tls1-2/main) and changed the appropriate sendmail.ini line to smtp_ssl=tls. TLS 1.2 is enabled in Windows.

Emails are no longer sent.

error.log says:

> Your mailbox cannot be accessed. Please activate TLS in your mail program.

debug.log says:

```
23/05/23 00:25:37 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
23/05/23 00:25:37 ** To: mail@ity.me.uk
23/05/23 00:25:37 ** Subject: Works!
23/05/23 00:25:37 ** X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:TESTMAIL.php
23/05/23 00:25:37 ** 
23/05/23 00:25:37 ** An email has been generated from your localhost, congratulations!
23/05/23 00:25:37 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
23/05/23 00:25:37 ** Authenticating with POP3 server
23/05/23 00:25:37 ** Connected.
23/05/23 00:25:37 << +OK POP server ready H mieue014 1MD6TB-1ps84e0Se1-0093l1<EOL>
23/05/23 00:25:37 >> CAPA<EOL>
23/05/23 00:25:37 << +OK Capability list follows<EOL>
23/05/23 00:25:37 << TOP<EOL>UIDL<EOL>STLS<EOL>SASL<EOL>IMPLEMENTATION trinity<EOL>.<EOL>
23/05/23 00:25:37 >> USER *@ray-crowther.me.uk<EOL>
23/05/23 00:25:37 << -ERR Your mailbox cannot be accessed. Please activate TLS in your mail program.<EOL>
23/05/23 00:25:37 ** Disconnected.
23/05/23 00:25:37 ** Disconnected.
23/05/23 00:25:37 ** Disconnected.
23/05/23 00:25:37 ** Your mailbox cannot be accessed. Please activate TLS in your mail program.<EOL>
```

Comment: Did you already restart the server sending the mail? Maybe old config is held in memory.

Comment: Yes, server restarted after any parameter changes.

Comment: As you haven't shared a single line of code, it's impossible to tell you why this happens. If this is a pure sendmail problem, please move it to serverfault.com

Comment: You can also use PHPMailer instead of SendMail to directly connect to the IONOS SMTP server.

Comment: Must be an IONOS issue. Swapped to using Gmail as mail host and now OK!?